# What is a delegate in Cocoa and why should I use them?

Tags: cocoa, delegates

I'm currently trying learning Cocoa and I am not sure if I understand that correctly... It's about **delegates** and **controllers**.

At first: What's the difference between the two? Sometimes I see code where a class is called `AppController`, sometimes - with more or less the same content - `AppDelegate`.

So, if I understand it correctly, a delegate is a simple object that receives messages when a certain event occurs. For example:

```
@interface WindowController : NSObject <NSWindowDelegate>
@end

@implementation WindowController
- (void)windowDidMiniaturize:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"-windowDidMiniaturize");
}
@end
```

Now, I use this code to make it a delegate of my `window`:

```
@interface TryingAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSWindow *window;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (retain) WindowController *winController;

@end
```

With the following implementation:

```
@implementation TryingAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize winController;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSLog(@"-applicationDidFinishLaunching:");

    self.winController = [[WindowController alloc] init];
    [window setDelegate:winController];

    [self.winController release];
}

@end
```

And now, whenever I minimize `window`, it will send a `-windowDidMiniaturize:` message to `WindowController`. Do I have that right?

If so, why don't you just subclass `NSWindow` rather than bothering with an additional class you have to take care of?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delegates are especially useful when you want one object to coordinate several others. For instance, you might create an `NSWindowController` subclass and make it it's window's delegate. That same window might contain several other elements (like `NSTextField`s) that you want to make the window controller a delegate of. This way you don't need to subclass the window and several of its controls. You can keep all the code that conceptually belongs together in the same class. In addition, delegates usually belong to the controller level of the Model-View-Controller concept. By subclassing `NSWindow` you would move controller type code to the view level.

A class can adopt any number of protocols, so `<NSWindowDelegate, NSTextFieldDelegate>` is perfectly valid. You can then set your object as the delegate of any number of windows and text fields. To find out what delegate messages a class like `NSTextField` supports check out the [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html).The `-delegate` and `-setDelegate:` methods will usually point you to the proper protocol. In our case this is [`NSTextFieldDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTextFieldDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSTextFieldDelegate). For classes that have been added to older version of Apple’s frameworks there often an additional section on delegate methods (either alongside “Class Methods” and “Instance Methods” or as a subsection of “Tasks”). Note that declaring your class as conforming to a delegate protocol will not have them magically delivered to your object – you must explicitly set it as the delegate:

```
@interface MyWindowController : NSWindowController <NSWindowDelegate, NSTextFieldDelegate> {
    NSTextField *_someTextField;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSTextField *someTextField;

@end


@implementation MyWindowController

@synthesize someTextField = _someTextField;

- (void)dealloc {
    [_someTextField release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];
    // When using a XIB/NIB, you can also set the File's Owner as the
    // delegate of the window and the text field.
    [[self window] setDelegate:self];
    [[self someTextField] setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)windowDidMiniaturize:(NSNotification *)notification {

}

- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textShouldEndEditing:(NSText *)fieldEditor {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

`AppController` and `AppDelegate` are just different naming conventions for the same type of class.

Comment: Thank you! What protocol does my controller need to conform to? I guess when I use NSWindowDelegateProtocol I can't make it a delegate of a `NSTextField`, do I? And which messages do I receive from those elements? Still `windowDidMiniaturize` and so on?

Comment: I’ve updated my answer to include some info about (delegate) protocols and an example.